# how to properly test the methods defined in the Main class by using JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, junit, junit4

I am new to Java so this could be a naive question. I created a `Main` class like below, and I would like to write some tests for the `getArrays`, `getAverage`, and `bubbleSortAscending` methods, just for the purpose of learning how to do unit tests.

```
public class Main {
        private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            int[] myArrays = getArrays(5);
            for (int i=0; i<myArrays.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("index = " + i + " value = " + myArrays[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("Average is " + getAverage(myArrays));

            int[] sortedArray = bubbleSortAscending(myArrays);
            System.out.println("Sorted: \r");
            for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
            }
        }

        public static int[] getArrays(int number) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + number + " integer values.\r");
            int[] values = new int[number];

            for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
                values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            return values;
        }

        public static double getAverage(int[] array) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                sum += array[i];
            }
            return sum / (double) array.length;
        }

        public static int[] bubbleSortAscending(int[] array) {
            for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<array.length - i - 1; j++){
                    int a = array[j];
                    int b = array[j+1];
                    if (a > b) {
                        int c = a;
                        a = b;
                        b = c;
                    }
                    array[j] = a;
                    array[j+1] = b;
                }
            }
            return array;
        }

    }
```

And IntelliJ automatically generated these test codes for me:

```
public class MainTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void getArrays() {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void getAverage() {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void bubbleSortAscending() {
    }

}
```

However, when I filled the first one with codes like this:

```
 @org.junit.Test
    public void getArrays() {
        int[] expectedArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] generatedArray = getArrays(5);
        assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, generatedArray);
    }
```

IntelliJ told me that something is wrong ...
[image]

So looks like it's because the `getArrays()` inside the `MainTest` is not taking any input argument? Why the `getArrays()` in the `MainTest` is not working the same as the `getArrays()` defined in the `Main`?

Comment: `getArrays` in the test class is a method in which you should put the unit test of the `getArrays` in your main class. That's the only relationship between them. I think that's bad naming, and you should rename the method to the case you are testing, e.g. `testGetArraysAcceptsEmptyArray`. Also as `getArrays` takes user input it will be hard to test, I think you should ignore it. When you have more experience you can pass a `Scanner` to the method, and provide a mocked instance of the Scanner for your tests, but don't get bogged down trying to do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are recursively calling (by mistake) the test method itself, which happens to have the same method name as the tested method.

The test method (`MainTest.getTest()`), in contrary to the tested method (`Main.getTest(int)`) does not have any parameter - hence the error message, that you cannot pass the `int` to that method.

You have to call the tested static method by specifying the class:

```
@Test
public void getArrays() {
   ...
   int[] generatedArray = Main.getArrays(5); // Call getArrays(int) in Main class
   ...
}
```

or change the method name, you will probably have more than one test method anyways:

```
@Test
public void getArraysReturnsNull() { ... }
// OR
@Test
public void testGetArrays() { ... }
...
```

Now you can use static import and call tested static method without clasifying the class:

```
import static segovia.java.learn.Main.getArrays;

@Test
public void testGetArrays() {
   int[] generatedArray = getArrays(); // OK now
}
```

**IntelliJ tip**:

Hold CTRL and click on the method name.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me now. So the lesson learned is that I shall not blindly use the codes automatically generated by IDE.